# how to sort xls file column wise and write it to another file with entire row using python?

Tags: python, file, sorting, xls

how to sort xls file column wise and write it to another file with entire row using python ? the xls file has to be sorted column wise. And after sorting it has to be writen into another file.

Comment: In what part of the problem are you facing the problem?

Comment: You can use COM with pywin32 and [Excel.Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7(v=vs.80).aspx) or the [Python-Excel](http://www.python-excel.org/) tools.  Check them out, then come back with specific problems.

Comment: Do you want to sort rows based on the contents of a given column or columns? sort columns based on the contents of a given row or rows? something else?

Comment: sort columns based on the contents of a given row or rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
     column = 0 #The column you want to sort by
     reader = list(csv.reader(open('input.xsl')))
     reader.sort(key=lambda x: x[column])
     writer = csv.writer(open('output.xsl', 'w'))
     writer.writerows(reader)
```

My bad, well you can always export as csv i guess. If you want to stick to xls you can use xlrd and xlwt. I haven't worked much with this but I do have a sample from a task I had to do a while back. Here it is(not that is not 100% good because the cell titles for each columns will be stored as the first row on data on the output file):

```
    import xlwt
    from xlrd import open_workbook

    target_column = 0

    book = open_workbook('input.xls', formatting_info=True)
    sheet = book.sheets()[0]
    data = [sheet.row_values(i) for i in xrange(sheet.nrows)]
    labels = data[0]
    data = data[1:]
    data.sort(key=lambda x: x[target_column])

    wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet = wbk.add_sheet(sheet.name)

    for idx, label in enumerate(labels):
         sheet.write(0, idx, label)

    for idx_r, row in enumerate(data):
        for idx_c, value in enumerate(row):
            sheet.write(idx_r+1, idx_c, value)

    wbk.save('result.xls')
```

Comment: i had used xlrd.open_workbook('sample.xls') . but not able to sort the file

Comment: how to append to existing xls file ?

Comment: the result.xls file is displaying date in not correct fromat. ie instead of date it is some number.

Comment: @halo: Read the xlrd docs (section on dates near the start) and the tutorial that you can obtain via http://www.python-excel.org