# xlrd / xlutils reordering spreadsheet rows

Tags: python

So I have an excel spreadsheet that has a specific column I want to sort the spreadsheet by. The column has 3 different combinations of starting letters, B,C,E. I want to order by B then E then all the rows starting with C. I do need to sort the whole table from the column

Anyone know how to do this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your sheet into a list of rows `lst`, the column index of your specific column being `index`.

```
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('myworkbook.xls')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
lst = [sh.row(n) for n in xrange(sh.nrows)]
searchdict = dict(B=1, E=2, C=3)
lst.sort(key=lambda row: searchdict.get(row[index][0], 4))
```

The `[0]` in the last line accesses the first character of your field, which is looked up in a dictionary then. The default value of 4 in the `dict.get` arguments puts all not fitting lines to the end of your new list. Not tested in detail, but should get you the idea.

Comment: So I think the problem here is that I have like 10 columns, and when I reorder I need all columns reordered, right?

Comment: Well, please be more precise about your requirements. Do you only want to reorder this one single column or the whole table according to this one column?

Comment: Then this should work for you as is. I was also not 100% sure what you meant with combinations of starting letters. Did you mean combination A='asdf', E='sdfsd' etc. or Axxx, Exxx, Cxxx? The answer would have to be slightly modified according to that.

Comment: They all start with the same 3 letters, but yea the column is Axxx, Exxx, Cxxxx

Comment: I keep getting int object is no iterable when trying this, any idea where I'm off?

Comment: I actually found a better work around, my logic was just bad and once I fixed that I didn't need to, but this did fix the problem at hand! Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [how to sort xls file column wise and write it to another file with entire row using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125465/how-to-sort-xls-file-column-wise-and-write-it-to-another-file-with-entire-row-us)

And in your sorting function (key), I would do something like this (not tested, add error checking) for the comparison. If you want to implement __gt__ and __lt__ then they're basically the same with the > switched to < .

```
    order = ['B','E','C'] #Set the order for the first letter here
    def gt( a, b ):

        if a[0] == b[0]:
          return a > b   #Same letter, use normal sorting
        else:
          return order.index(a[0]) > order.index(b[0])   #Sort using first letter
```

Note: If your question was NOT asking to sort passed the first letter, then go with the other answer.