# how to make a custom sort for an excel spreadsheet using python

Tags: python, linux, excel, sorting

So I have an excel spreadsheet where I need to sort the rows by one column which represents the criticality of the object in the row with the values: Critical, High, Medium, Low, Info.  I need critical to be at the top and then for the rest to fall in after that, i found this looking for sort [xlrd / xlutils reordering spreadsheet rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632858/xlrd-xlutils-reordering-spreadsheet-rows) but I'm wondering if there's a way to make a custom sort like I described above.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Use the answer you've linked to and amend `dict(B=1, E=2, C=3)` to be `dict(Critical=1, High=2...)`... Or if you don't care, and just want critical first, then just put that in the dict by itself

Comment: thanks, i really didn't understand that line that he was using.