# How to sort Excel sheet using Python

Tags: python, xlrd

I am using Python 3.4 and xlrd. I want to sort the Excel sheet based on the primary column before processing it. Is there any library to perform this ?

Comment: Get the column in a list, then `sorted(list)` .

Answer (score 13):

There are a couple ways to do this. The first option is to utilize [`xlrd`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd), as you have this tagged. The biggest downside to this is that it doesn't natively write to XLSX format.

These examples use an excel document with this format:

[image: Text Excel Layout]

Utilizing `xlrd` and a few modifications from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9125563/189134):

```
import xlwt
from xlrd import open_workbook

target_column = 0     # This example only has 1 column, and it is 0 indexed

book = open_workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheets()[0]
data = [sheet.row_values(i) for i in xrange(sheet.nrows)]
labels = data[0]    # Don't sort our headers
data = data[1:]     # Data begins on the second row
data.sort(key=lambda x: x[target_column])

bk = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = bk.add_sheet(sheet.name)

for idx, label in enumerate(labels):
     sheet.write(0, idx, label)

for idx_r, row in enumerate(data):
    for idx_c, value in enumerate(row):
        sheet.write(idx_r+1, idx_c, value)

bk.save('result.xls')    # Notice this is xls, not xlsx like the original file is
```

This outputs the following workbook:

[image: XLRD output]

---

Another option (and one that can utilize XLSX output) is to utilize [`pandas`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas). The code is also shorter:

```
import pandas as pd

xl = pd.ExcelFile("test.xlsx")
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
df = df.sort(columns="Header Row")

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1',columns=["Header Row"],index=False)
writer.save()
```

This outputs:

[image: Pandas Output]

In the [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) call, the `index` is set to `False`, so that the Pandas dataframe index isn't included in the excel document. The rest of the keywords should be self explanatory.

Answer (score 9):

I just wanted to refresh the answer as the Pandas implementation has changed a bit over time. Here's the code that should work now (pandas 1.1.2).

```
import pandas as pd

xl = pd.ExcelFile("test.xlsx")
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
df = df.sort_values(by="Header Row")
...
```

The `sort` function is now called `sort_by` and `columns` is replaced by `by`.