# Sorting an excel file and sending a daily email using python

Tags: python, excel

Firstly I do apologies if my question might sound silly or irrelevant. I do not have a high level in any kind of coding language.

I am currently using( playing around with python) and I was wondering if I can automate a process that I deal with every day and I currently do manually.
I have an excel spreadsheet that I sort everyday based on the same criteria and I sent it afterwards via email .

Any help.idea.tips.tricks more then welcome

Comment: Please read through some [references](http://www.python-excel.org/), give it a shot yourself, then come back if you get stuck.  Folks on this website will help you solve specific problems, most will not write code for you.

Comment: The work you put in now will pay off in the long run. I believe you can do it!

Comment: Thank you all, extremely helpfull insights :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out Openpyxl for the excel and SMTP for the emails, can use schedule to schedule it everyday, shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27470418/4692404) for sort Excel sheet using Python. You can use either [`xlrd`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) or [`pandas`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas) to read, sort and write excel files. For `pandas`, use [`sort_values()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values) instead of `sort()` to sort data. For example, you can replace `df.sort` line by:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=["col_0", "col_1", "col_2"], ascending=[False, True, False])
```

After saving the sorted data to excel file, refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25394911/4692404) to send emails with Python.

Comment: thanks, that's very helpfull especially since I am already using pandas.