# how to write sheets in order in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I’m writing dataframe to 5 Excel sheets using  df.to_excel().
eg:

```
  df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Invoice details', index=False) 
  df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Invoice Summary', index=False)
```

Is there a way to indicate how to arrange the sheets by order while writing them?
That‘s, I want `Invoice summary sheet` should be first sheet while, `invoice details sheet` should be last sheet

Comment: I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27469182) in stack may it can help.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`with` context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers), and then specify the files in the desired order.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'total_invoices': [2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'invoice_no': [1, 2]})

with pd.ExcelWriter('invoices.xlsx') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Invoice Summary', index=False)
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Invoice details', index=False)
```